# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component when other functions work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have storeMethods that im using as replacement of a redux container. The issue im having is that its not executing this function, all the other functions work like editComment, likePost, etc.

```
storeMethods().createPost(postData);
```

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the
>   body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
>   following reasons:

**storeHooks.tsx**

```
import usePostsHook from "./postsHook";
import useNotificationHook from "./notificationHook";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { likePostInit, dislikePostInit, deletePostInit, createPostInit, addTitle, addContent, deleteCommentInit, editCommentInit, postCommentInit } from "../../actions/postActions";
import { getIsNotified, getUser, getBodyError, getTitleError, postContent, title } from "../../selectors/selectors";
function useStoreMethods() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [posts] = usePostsHook();
    const [notifications] = useNotificationHook();
    const isNotified = useSelector(getIsNotified());
    const user = useSelector(getUser());
    const likePost = (id: number) => dispatch(likePostInit(id));
    const dislikePost = (id: number) => dispatch(dislikePostInit(id));
    const deletePost = (id: number, userId: number) => dispatch(deletePostInit(id, userId));
    const deleteComment = (id: number, postId: number, userId: number) => dispatch(deleteCommentInit(id, postId, userId));
    const postComment = (commentData: object) => dispatch(postCommentInit(commentData));
    const editComment = (commentData) => dispatch(editCommentInit(commentData));
    const createPost = (postData: object) => dispatch(createPostInit(postData));
    const ourTitle = useSelector(title());
    const titleError = useSelector(getTitleError());
    const ourBodyError = useSelector(getBodyError());
    const ourPostContent = useSelector(postContent());

    return {
        posts,
        notifications,
        user,
        isNotified,
        likePost,
        dislikePost,
        deletePost,
        deleteComment,
        postComment,
        editComment,
        createPost,
        ourTitle,
        titleError,
        ourBodyError,
        ourPostContent,
    };
}

export default useStoreMethods;
```

I'm using it like this

**Dashboard.tsx**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import PostForm from "../forms/createPost/createPost";
import GridHoc from "../hoc/grid";
import OurTabs from "../tabs/OurTabs";
import { InputHook } from "../common/handleHook";
import usePostsHook from "./../common/postsHook";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { createPostInit, addTitle, addContent } from "../../actions/postActions";
import { getBodyError, getTitleError, postContent, title } from "../../selectors/selectors";
import storeMethods from "./../common/storeHooks";
function Dashboard(props: any) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const inputData = {
        addTitle: (data: string) => dispatch(addTitle(data)),
        addContent: (data: string) => dispatch(addContent(data)),
    };
    const { handleInputChange } = InputHook(inputData);
    const ourTitle = storeMethods().ourTitle;
    const titleError = storeMethods().titleError;
    const ourBodyError = storeMethods().ourBodyError;
    const ourPostContent = storeMethods().ourPostContent;
    const onSubmit = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const postData = { ourTitle, ourPostContent };
        console.log(postData);
        storeMethods().createPost(postData);
    };
    const isEnabled = titleError === true && ourBodyError === true ? false : true;
    console.log("fffgg", props);
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Grid justify="center" container={true}>
                <Grid item={true} lg={9} xs={11}>
                    <PostForm
                        title={ourTitle}
                        postContent={ourPostContent}
                        handleTitleChange={handleInputChange}
                        handleContentChange={handleInputChange}
                        onSubmit={onSubmit}
                        disButton={isEnabled}
                        titleError={titleError}
                        bodyError={ourBodyError}
                    />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <br />

            <OurTabs />
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default GridHoc(Dashboard);
// will be useful for unit testing.
export { Dashboard as DashboardComponent };
```

Comment: Can you please return the full  code for that last block?

Comment: Where do you assign/import `ourPostContent` ? `storeMethods` is `useStoreMethods` ?

Comment: sure let me share code

Comment: i updated last block of code, hope this gives a better idea.

Comment: @IgnacioLago Yes storeMethods is useStoreMethods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are calling the hook inside the body of `onSubmit` rather than at the top level of the function component (see [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)).

Try instead:

```
....
const ourPostContent = storeMethods().ourPostContent;
const { createPost } = storeMethods();
const onSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const postData = { ourTitle, ourPostContent };
    console.log(postData);
    createPost(postData);
};
```

I used the destructuring pattern here because I think it may suit your use case more cleanly, but feel free to also write it in the way you had it before.

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly, thank you for explanation.